# tastypie posting and full example

Tags: django, api, tastypie

Is there a full tastypie django example site and setup available for download? I have been wrestling with wrapping my head around it all day. I have the following code. Basically, I have a POST form that is handled with ajax. When I click "submit" on my form and the ajax request runs, the call returns "POST http://192.168.1.110:8000/api/private/client_basic_info/ 404 (NOT FOUND)" I have the URL configured alright, I think. I can access http://192.168.1.110:8000/api/private/client_basic_info/?format=json just fine. Am I missing some settings or making some fundamental errors in my methods? My intent is that each user can fill out/modify one and only one "client basic information" form/model.

a page:

```
{% extends "layout-column-100.html" %}
{% load uni_form_tags sekizai_tags %}

{% block title %}Basic Information{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}

    {% addtoblock "js" %}
        <script language="JavaScript">

        $(document).ready( function() {

            $('#client_basic_info_form').submit(function (e) {

                form = $(this)

                form.find('span.error-message, span.success-message').remove()
                form.find('.invalid').removeClass('invalid')
                form.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')

                e.preventDefault();
                var values = {}

                $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
                    values[field.name] = field.value;
                })


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(values),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false,
                    url: '/api/private/client_basic_info/',
                    success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                        form.find('input[type="submit"]')
                            .after('<span class="success-message">Saved successfully!</span>')
                            .removeAttr('disabled')
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        console.log(jqXHR)
                        console.log(textStatus)
                        console.log(errorThrown)

                        var errors = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText)
                        for (field in errors) {
                            var field_error = errors[field][0]
                            $('#id_' + field).addClass('invalid')
                                .after('<span class="error-message">'+ field_error +'</span>')
                        } 
                        form.find('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled')
                    }
                }) // end $.ajax()

            }) // end $('#client_basic_info_form').submit()

        }) // end $(document).ready()

        </script>
    {% endaddtoblock %}


{% uni_form form form.helper %}


{% endblock %}
```

resources

```
from residence.models import ClientBasicInfo
from residence.forms.profiler import ClientBasicInfoForm

from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization, Authorization
from tastypie.validation import FormValidation
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        fields = ['username']
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }
        include_resource_uri = False
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        forms_incomplete = []

        if ClientBasicInfo.objects.filter(user=bundle.request.user).count() < 1:
            forms_incomplete.append({'name': 'Basic Information', 'url': reverse('client_basic_info')})

        bundle.data['forms_incomplete'] = forms_incomplete
        return bundle


class ClientBasicInfoResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')


    class Meta:
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        include_resource_uri = False
        queryset = ClientBasicInfo.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'client_basic_info'
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=ClientBasicInfoForm)
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', ]
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
```

Edit:

My resources file is now:

```
from residence.models import ClientBasicInfo
from residence.forms.profiler import ClientBasicInfoForm

from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization, Authorization
from tastypie.validation import FormValidation
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        fields = ['username']
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }
        include_resource_uri = False
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

    #def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
    #    return object_list.filter(username=request.user)

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        forms_incomplete = []

        if ClientBasicInfo.objects.filter(user=bundle.request.user).count() < 1:
            forms_incomplete.append({'name': 'Basic Information', 'url': reverse('client_basic_info')})

        bundle.data['forms_incomplete'] = forms_incomplete
        return bundle


class ClientBasicInfoResource(ModelResource):
    # user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        include_resource_uri = False
        queryset = ClientBasicInfo.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'client_basic_info'
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=ClientBasicInfoForm)
        #list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', ]
        #detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(user=request.user)
```

I made the user field of the ClientBasicInfo nullable and the POST seems to work. I want to try updating the entry now. Would that just be appending the pk to the ajax url? For example /api/private/client_basic_info/21/? When I submit that form I get a 501 NOT IMPLEMENTED message. What exactly haven't I implemented? I am subclassing ModelResource, which should have all the ORM-related functions implemented according to the docs.

Comment: Maybe some problem with APPEND_SLASHES? Have you tried posting to http://192.168.1.110:8000/api/private/client_basic_info (without trailing slash)? Just a guess.

Comment: Hmm I took the slash off the url and got "You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set." I applied APPEND_SLASH = False to my settings and now I get a 403 Forbidden message (CSRF verification failed). I got past that by making the view csrf_exempt. Now I get a 501 not implemented error. I added a custom hydrate function and got past that. I try to submit a form to update the object but I get another error. Error after error, I think I will just give up with tastypie.

Comment: I'm not a TastyPie expert, so I can only make more guesses. Have you tried using different Authentication and Authorization backends?Try to use tastypie's `Authorization` and `Authentication` classes for authorization and authentication, respectively. They should be very permissive. Just to check if that's the problem.

Comment: I just changed both to Authorization and Authentication, the all-permissive ones and I still get 501 not implemented error.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured it out. I wasn't being careful. The AJAX request type should have been "PUT" to handle the 501 not implemented error (I was performing an update). I have also set up a custom authentication class to handle 403 errors.